# Datatabase error: Commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, errors

I have create function with code bellow:

```
function my_add_new_id ( ) {
...
$GetSvrPass = $my_db_connect->get_var ( $my_db_connect->prepare ( 'CALL my_acquireuserpasswd ( %s, @ID, @PASS ) ;', $mylogin ) );
$GetPassVarHex = $GetSvrPass;
if ( ( $garamold !== $GetPassVarHex ) || ( $twpinold !== $GetPin ) ) {
$my_add_id_message .= '<div class="my-alert-box myerror"><span>FAILED:</span> Old Password and Old Pin not match</div>';
}
else {      
     $my_db_connect->query ( $my_db_connect->prepare ( 'CALL my_add_other_id ( %s, '.$garam.', %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %d ) ; ', $mylogin, $cPanel, $mypass, $my_wpname, $USER_IP, $my_wpemail, $mypin, $my_wpid, $my_svr_region ) );
     $my_add_id_message .= '<div class="my-alert-box mysuccess"><span>SUCCESS:</span> New ID has been added to your account! </div>';
     }
echo $my_add_id_message;
}
```

and mysql Procedure and function bellow:

```
    MYSQL PROCEDURE: my_acquireuserpasswd
    =======================================
    BEGIN
      DECLARE passwdtemp VARCHAR(64);
      START TRANSACTION;
        SELECT id, passwd INTO uid1, passwdtemp FROM users WHERE name = name1;
        SELECT fn_varbintohexsubstring(1,passwdtemp,1,0) ;
      COMMIT;
    END
    ================================================================
    PARAMETER: in name1 VARCHAR(64), out uid1 INTEGER, out passwd1 VARCHAR(64)
    ================================================================
```

Every time I execute the function I always got

> WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]

Those error always appear when I execute the function on form.
it give

> WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]

on `CALL my_add_other_id`

I have re-check those Procedure, there is nothing wrong with it.
but the message always say can't run `my_add_other_id`

I think the problem is in

```
$GetSvrPass = $my_db_connect->get_var ( $my_db_connect->prepare ( 'CALL my_acquireuserpasswd ( %s, @ID, @PASS ) ;', $mylogin ) );
```

where it calling procedure `my_acquireuserpasswd` and at that procedure it will select function `fn_varbintohexsubstring` and seems the problem on that function.
but i don't know where the problem is, since i try run it without wordpress, it can run without any error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's way too much code to debug dude.  You need to go line by line and figure out where the issue is.

Comment: @AndrewBartel i edit the post on the last line. I think the problem is in `fn_varbintohexsubstring` and seems the problem on that function. but i don't know where the problem is, since i try run it without wordpress, it can run without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with "orphaned SELECT statements". It is described  [here](http://www.coderrants.com/wordpress-and-stored-procedures/) in more detail.

One solution would be to create a temporary table and modify `my_acquireuserpasswd` to save data to `temp_table`

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE passwdtemp VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE temp VARCHAR(4000);
  START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT id, passwd INTO uid1, passwdtemp FROM users WHERE name = name1;
    SET temp = fn_varbintohexsubstring(1,passwdtemp,1,0) ;
    INSERT INTO temp_table (pstrout) VALUES (temp); 
  COMMIT;
END
```

Assuming $my_db_connect is $wpdb object, you can retrieve the data in your php function using something like:

```
     $GetSvrPass = $my_db_connect->get_var ( 'SELECT * FROM temp_table' );
     $my_db_connect->query ( 'DELETE FROM temp_table' );
```

Deleting values from temp_table at every function call is of course optional, you might simply add ID's or implement some other solution.

Comment: thank you, your answer really helpful, now i can run the query with right way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375186/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-in-wordpress-php-5-4